# How to extract values of a deeply nested list if some elements are already NA at higher level?

Tags: r, list, nested, extract, na

From a deeply nested list I want to extract the values of a specific cell. Some of the sub lists are already `NA` at a higher level, so that the loop that wants to extract the value of a deeper level would yield an error.

```
sapply(1:length(li), function(i) li[[i]][[1]]$b$l[2])
# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I'm not sure how to omit `NA`s in such a structure, e.g. this fails with the same error:

```
sapply(1:length(li), function(i) na.omit(li[[i]][[1]]$b$l[2]))
```

Finally a `try()` attempt gives **the desired result**, but the error is still in the result and I have to annoyingly `grep()` it out.

```
r <- sapply(1:length(li), function(i) try(li[[i]][[1]]$b$l[2], TRUE))
r[grep("Error", r)] <- NA
r
# [1] "2"  "22" NA  # <- desired result
```

Could this be solved more elegantly in **base R**? I also want to avoid to clown around with `if`-`else`s.

I like the following but I have no idea how to use it to omit the `NA`s à la `dat[!is.na(dat)]`:

```
rapply(li, function(x) !is.na(x), h="l")
```

#### Data

```
li <- list(list(list(a=list(k=1:3, l=1:3), b=list(k=1:3, l=1:3))),
           list(list(a=list(k=21:23, l=21:23), b=list(k=21:23, l=21:23))),
           list(list(a=NA, b=NA)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one efficient way to avoid getting errors is the use of `tryCatch()`:

```
r <- sapply(1:length(li), function(i) tryCatch(li[[i]][[1]]$b$l[2], error = function(e) NA))
```

This will ensure that you always get an `NA` when there is any type of error which is a very useful return value.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `purrr` package you can do

```
map_dbl(li, ~pluck(., 1, "b","l", 2, .default=NA))
```

The `pluck()` function will always return a value even when the path doesn't exist and we can set a default value of `NA` for when that happens

You can also write you own helper in base R.

```
base_pluck <- function(x, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  for(i in dots) {
    if (is.numeric(i) && i>=1 && i <= length(x)) {
      x <- x[[i]]
    } else if( is.character(i) && hasName(x, i)) {
      x <- x[[i]]  
    } else {
      return(NA)
    }
  }
  x
}

sapply(li, function(x) base_pluck(x, 1, "b" , "l", 2))
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to update, actually I need `NA` where there's an "error" resp. a missing value.

Comment: @jay.sf Well, that just avoids the need for the unlist with some small adjustments. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution without `tryCatch`ing: after `unlist`ing, elements are labeled according to their names and position in `b` where we want `"l2`".

```
unname(sapply(sapply(1:length(li), function(i) unlist(li[[i]][[1]]$b)), `[`, "l2"))
# [1]  2 22 NA
```